# Finding the difference between two dataframes having duplicate records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of product listings (Product, Price and Vendor)

Scrape 1:

```
    Product Price   Vendor
0   ABC123  121.50  VendorB
1   GHIJK   76.45   VendorA
2   KLMNOP  55.05   VendorB
3   XYZABC  67.01   VendorC
4   JKJKABC 9.15    VendorX
5   XYZXYZ  78.05   VendorJ
6   XYZ1234 90.90   VendorI
```

and Scrape 2:

```
   Product  Price   Vendor
0   ABC123  121.50  VendorB
1   GHIJK   76.45   VendorA
2   XYZABC  67.01   VendorC
3   JKJKABC 9.15    VendorX
4   XYZ1234 90.90   VendorI
5   HIJKLM  89.75   VendorC
6   LOLOLOL 23.55   VendorI
7   WENDY   89.02   VendorG
8   ROAD123 90.99   Vendor4U
9   FORGE12 67.59   VendorX
```

from where I wanted to find out the difference in listings (i.e the new listings in `Scrape 2` and the sold listings from `Scrape 1`.

I did this by doing a merge on the two dataframes -

```
# SOLD LISTINGS - LISTINGS ONLY IN FIRST DATAFRAME
df_sold = df_scrape_1.merge(df_scrape_2,indicator = True, how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']!='both']

# NEW LISTINGS - LISTINGS ONLY IN SECOND DATAFRAME
df_new = df_scrape_1.merge(df_scrape_2,indicator = True, how='right').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']!='both']
```

which gives me the correct result, `2 Sold` listings and `5 New` listings. But I ran into problems when I have some duplicate rows in either of the scrapes.

For example, if Scrape 1 has 3 duplicate listings of `ABC123` and only 1 of them is present in Scrape 2, it should show as `2 Sold` Listings. Or, if Scrape 1 has 1 listing of `XYZXYZ` and Scrape 2 has 3 of those, it should be show as `2 New` listings. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

If I have Scrape 1:

```
    Product Price   Vendor
0   ABC123  121.50  VendorB
1   GHIJK   76.45   VendorA
2   KLMNOP  55.05   VendorB
3   XYZABC  67.01   VendorC
4   ABC123  121.50  VendorB
5   JKJKABC 9.15    VendorX
6   XYZXYZ  78.05   VendorJ
7   XYZ1234 90.90   VendorI
```

and Scrape 2 as:

```
   Product  Price   Vendor
0   ABC123  121.50  VendorB
1   GHIJK   76.45   VendorA
2   XYZABC  67.01   VendorC
3   JKJKABC 9.15    VendorX
4   XYZ1234 90.90   VendorI
5   HIJKLM  89.75   VendorC
6   LOLOLOL 23.55   VendorI
7   WENDY   89.02   VendorG
8   ROAD123 90.99   Vendor4U
9   FORGE12 67.59   VendorX
10  XYZABC  67.01   VendorC
11  XYZABC  67.01   VendorC
```

It should give me two dataframes with `3 Sold` Listings and `7 New` Listings respectively.

Comment: If your problem is dealing with duplicates, then please provide a [mvce] that includes duplicates as well as your expected output in those cases. It's unclear whether it's just the item, or everything which is duplicated.

Comment: @ALollz I need this for every item (product) that is duplicated (has the same Product, Price and Vendor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to add a column adding an integer *index* (a rolling count) for each group of duplicated values.

For example, let us change `df_scrape_1` to:

```
   Product   Price   Vendor
0   ABC123  121.50  VendorB
1    GHIJK   76.45  VendorA
2   KLMNOP   55.05  VendorB
3   XYZABC   67.01  VendorC
4  JKJKABC    9.15  VendorX
5   XYZXYZ   78.05  VendorJ
6  XYZ1234   90.90  VendorI
7   ABC123  121.50  VendorB
```

where last line is a duplicate of the first one.

Let us add a rolling count for duplicated rows in both dataframes:

```
df_scrape_1['num'] = df_scrape_1.groupby(df_scrape_1.columns.tolist()).cumcount()
df_scrape_2['num'] = df_scrape_2.groupby(df_scrape_2.columns.tolist()).cumcount()
```

`df_scrape_1` has become:

```
   Product   Price   Vendor  num
0   ABC123  121.50  VendorB    0
1    GHIJK   76.45  VendorA    0
2   KLMNOP   55.05  VendorB    0
3   XYZABC   67.01  VendorC    0
4  JKJKABC    9.15  VendorX    0
5   XYZXYZ   78.05  VendorJ    0
6  XYZ1234   90.90  VendorI    0
7   ABC123  121.50  VendorB    1
```

And `df_sold` using your expression is now as expected:

```
df_sold = df_scrape_1.merge(df_scrape_2,indicator = True,
                            how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']!='both']
```

giving:

```
  Product   Price   Vendor  num     _merge
2  KLMNOP   55.05  VendorB    0  left_only
5  XYZXYZ   78.05  VendorJ    0  left_only
7  ABC123  121.50  VendorB    1  left_only
```

Answer (score 0):

A method as you've found is to use isin which will produce NaN rows which you can drop:

```
differences = df2[~df2.isin(df1)].dropna()
```

Comment: I tried that first, but I need separate dataframes for sold and new listings. That's why I switched to merge.