# Comparing Pandas Dataframes on unequal length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes as below:
'''
df1 =

| emp_id | emp_name | e_city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | Acity |
| 2 | Nick | Bcity |
| 3 | Sam | Ccity |
| 4 | John | Dcity |
| 5 | Mike | Ecity |

df2 =

| emp_id | emp_name | e_city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Nick | Bcity |
| 2 | Nick | Bcity |
| 3 | Sam | Ccity |
| 4 | John | Dcity |

'''
Please note df2 has a duplicate row and len of both DFs are not equal.
My use case is to find the mismatches or differences between these two DFs

expected output: - The row which is occurring only once in 1 DF and twice in another DF should be shown as a difference along with other mismatched values

df3 =

| emp_id | emp_name | e_city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | Acity |
| 2 | Nick | Bcity |
| 5 | Mike | Ecity |

I tried below methods but nothing were fruitful.

1. I cannot use 'df.compare' since both dataframes are not of equal length.
2. I tried using 'df.merge' but it is not pointing the duplicated row as a mismatch/difference.
3. I tried to use 'concate' and 'compare'. That is not successful as well.
   Can someone please help me on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of this question. Note that you can only compare the emp_id columns. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106227/difference-between-two-lists-with-duplicates-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the difference between two dataframes having duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484901/finding-the-difference-between-two-dataframes-having-duplicate-records) (Serge's  answer is the correct way)

Comment: @HarryPlotter.. Thank you! This answers my question. This is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

first you can `count` `duplicate` with `groupby`

```
df2 = df2.groupby(['emp_id','emp_name']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

and then merge the dataframe with original

Comment: Thanks for your response Suraj. I do not want to drop the duplicates. I want them to include in the output report and tag them as mismatched records (along with other mismatched values if any). So, could you please help me with that?

Comment: can u pass expected output?

Comment: df3 mentioned in the description of this question is the expected output

Comment: it is not clear what you want

Comment: Edited the question. Please check if it's clear now...